# Controlador de ficheros en ejecución AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, asynctask

Antes de exponer la pregunta, explico el entorno en el que necesito desarrollar la solución.

Disponemos del fichero index.php, donde el usuario tiene un textarea y un botón tipo submit en un formulario. En ese texarea el usuario va a pegar desde un excel una serie de líneas, cada línea contiene el nombre de un archivo sin extensión, algo tipo

```
file1
file2
file3
...
fileN
```

Bien, una vez pulsado el botón, lo que necesito gestionar (creo que lo ideal sería AJAX) es que se lance una petición hacia el fichero 'download.php' (que ya hace lo que tiene que hacer correctamente).

La gracia de esto es que, pongamos que fileN es file400 por ejemplo. No vamos a lanzar 400 peticiones a la vez por ajax hacia el fichero download.php, es absurdo, de modo que lo que intento hacer es delimitar un máximo de peticiones simultáneas hacia ese fichero, por ejemplo 4, y que mientras haya 4 ficheros download.php "trabajando" en sus cosas, el resto de ficheros estén en cola, esperando a que uno de los ocupados se libere, y entonces poder hacer la nueva petición.

En el siguiente código hace la petición de todos los ficheros a la vez, pero como digo, la idea es que haya un límite y se queden el resto encolados.

Todas las variables tienen sus valores correctos y llegan bien hasta el script, y el fichero php lo que hace en realidad es ir a un ftp ya definido, captura el fichero que le pasamos por POST, lo copia en varias ubicaciones definidas también y luego imprime OK o ERROR {fileName} que es lo que recogemos en el function(respuesta) y lo imprimimos en pantalla para ver el progreso.

```
var cantidadFicheros = arrFiles.length;
for (var i = cantidadFicheros; i >= 0; i--) {
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'download.php',
  data: { fichero:arrFiles[i], ruta:ruta },

  success: function(respuesta) {
    $(resultado).append("<p>" + respuesta + "</p>");
  },
  error: function(respuesta) {
    $(resultado).append("<p>" + respuesta + "</p>");
  }
})
}
```

El código que he puesto para que haga lo que comentaba, entran los primeros 4 ficheros, se ponen a descargarse y cuando acaba el primero, entra el primero de la cola y el resto sigue esperando. Los ficheros pueden ser de cualquier tamaño, desde pocos kb hasta varios Gb.

A ver si conseguimos sacarlo entre todos con un poquito de ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con una lista de la cual se van sacando items hasta que ya no queden.

```
var ruta = "";
var colaFicheros = arrFiles;

function traeUnFichero(id) {
  console.log("worker id", id);
  if (colaFicheros.length > 0) {
    var elFichero = colaFicheros.shift();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'download.php',
      data: {
        fichero: elFichero,
        ruta: ruta
      },
      success: function(respuesta) {
        $(resultado).append("<p>" + respuesta + "</p>");
      },
      error: function(respuesta) {
        $(resultado).append("<p>" + respuesta + "</p>");
      }
      complete: function(r) {
        setTimeOut(function() {
          traeUnFichero(id);
        }, 500); // una pausa y saca otro
      }
    })
  }
}

var trae1 = traeUnFichero(1);
var trae2 = traeUnFichero(2);
var trae3 = traeUnFichero(3);
var trae4 = traeUnFichero(4);
```

Comment: Estupendo !! Mil gracias @alo-Malbarez !! Al final sólo he tenido que retocar levemente tu código para poder encajarlo bien en el funcionamiento de mi script, añadiendo un par de timeouts por delante y por detrás para dar un cierto margen de tiempo a los scripts anteriores y posteriores para que no se pisen mutuamente.