# PHP Mostrar el contenido mientras se ejecuta una acción

Tags: php, laravel, php5, php7, lumen

tengo esta función **readMigration** que hace una llamada a diversas funciones , una de ellas es **readFile** que devuelve una respuesta Json , lo que intento es que mientras hace las distintas funciones muestre algo por pantalla , para ello intengo hacer uso del buffer de php pero no consigo que muestre nada por pantalla.

Gracias,

```
public function readFile():JsonResponse
{
    $count=0;
    $academicPrograms = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('Select *  from mitabla');

    foreach ($items as $item) {
      ...
    }
    return $this->jsonOkResponse($count);
 }




public function readMigration()
{
    ob_start();
    $this->readFile();
    $out = ob_get_clean();
    var_dump($out);

    ob_start();
    $this->otraFuncion....();
    $out = ob_get_clean();
    var_dump($out);
 }
```

Comment: La respuesta a tu pregunta es compleja. Para poder hacer eso, necesitas que tu función que procesa `readMigration` sea ejecutada de manera asíncrona. Además, tiene que tener actualización en algún espacio de memoria compartida (ejemplo: un archivo o una base de datos) para que pueda haber otro método HTTP que, con AJAX, pueda identificar el progreso. Llamando a este método, con JavaScript, puedes ir actualizando el progreso en pantalla.

Comment: Esta pregunta que hice hace un tiempo igual te ayuda. Tal como dice Pablo, debes hacerlo con AJAX, para que se ejecute de forma asíncrona, mientras tú ejecutas algo, puede estar ocupado otro fichero trabajando en paralelo. Echa un ojo a ver si te puede ayudar en algo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156529/controlador-de-ficheros-en-ejecuci%C3%B3n-ajax

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos por la respuesta , investigo por aquí. 1000 gracias